# Application crashes while running python file which uses wxpython Cocoa3.0 in mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working on a Python project which uses wxPython and it works fine with python2.7 on windows 7, 32 bit. Now I am trying to install this project in Mac which has a Python 2.7.5, 64 bit. I installed WxPython Cocoa3.0 which is for 64 bit. The application crashes when I work on certain cases whereas it works fine for the rest. I have pasted the error which I got in the following link. Please help me with this problem.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lrajmohan/PyView/master/ExpSuite%20-%20Copy/ExpSuite/TMP/Error_mac

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to exactly diagnose your problem without the code, but I've seen this issue before. A possible and well explained answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246160/textctrl-providing-an-out-of-bound-exception-in-wxpython).

Comment: Hello RobinDunn, you can see the whole code here: github.com/lrajmohan/PyView The problem arises in : https://github.com/lrajmohan/PyView/blob/master/ExpSuite%20-%20Copy/ExpSuite/PyView/PyView.py ,while pressing the lever button after it is run. –

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, an application running on a 32-bit Mac moved to 64-bit and wx3.0 crashed out on certain mouse clicks (but not all). I fixed this with a CallAfter:

```
def OnClickEdit(self, event):
    """Edit clicked, show menu."""
    def onclickedit():
        menu = wx.Menu()
        ...
        self.PopupMenu(menu)
        menu.Destroy()
    wx.CallAfter(onclickedit)
```