# Application crashed while giving input to wxPython GUI

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, crash, wxpython

I am using wxPython API to build an application and it works fine in windows 7. And now I installed wxpython CoCoa3.0 for mac and tried to run the same application. The application crashes when the input is given. I get the following error log. Any help will be appreciated.

```
7-16 16:06:54.507 Python[2999:d07] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-07-16 16:06:54.507 Python[2999:d07] NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds
2014-07-16 16:06:54.508 Python[2999:d07] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9255a25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90491e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9255a10c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff93ad3a05 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 140
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b510c54 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 303
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b63d51c -[NSTextView _markForTextCheckingAfterChange] + 431
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956ce1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956cb28d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956d2ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff924c15a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9247c7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9247bf25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bada0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bad7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bad5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3dc26e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3db8bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3cf9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    18  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x00000001052773b8 _ZN14wxGUIEventLoop8OSXDoRunEv + 248
    19  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x00000001051452af _ZN13wxCFEventLoop5DoRunEv + 31
    20  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x000000010507d751 _ZN15wxEventLoopBase3RunEv + 65
    21  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x0000000105042d97 _ZN16wxAppConsoleBase8MainLoopEv + 103
    22  _core_.so                           0x0000000104d5641c _ZN7wxPyApp8MainLoopEv + 76
    23  _core_.so                           0x0000000104da0d4f _wrap_PyApp_MainLoop + 79
    24  Python                              0x000000010479012f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16242
    25  Python                              0x000000010478c093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
    26  Python                              0x0000000104733796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809
    27  Python                              0x0000000104715f72 PyObject_Call + 101
    28  Python                              0x00000001047209a7 PyMethod_New + 1200
    29  Python                              0x0000000104715f72 PyObject_Call + 101
    30  Python                              0x000000010478fdf5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416
    31  Python                              0x0000000104792864 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 829
    32  Python                              0x000000010478f4d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
    33  Python                              0x0000000104792864 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 829
    34  Python                              0x000000010478f4d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
    35  Python                              0x000000010478c093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
    36  Python                              0x000000010478ba24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    37  Python                              0x00000001047aac2c PyParser_ASTFromFile + 306
    38  Python                              0x00000001047aacd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137
    39  Python                              0x00000001047aa821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718
    40  Python                              0x00000001047bb363 Py_Main + 2995
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff958bd5fd start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
2014-07-16 16:06:54.509 Python[2999:d07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9255a25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90491e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9255a10c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff93ad3a05 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 140
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b510c54 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 303
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b63d51c -[NSTextView _markForTextCheckingAfterChange] + 431
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956ce1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956cb28d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff956d2ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff924c15a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9247c7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9247bf25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bada0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bad7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94bad5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3dc26e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3db8bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3cf9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    18  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x00000001052773b8 _ZN14wxGUIEventLoop8OSXDoRunEv + 248
    19  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x00000001051452af _ZN13wxCFEventLoop5DoRunEv + 31
    20  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x000000010507d751 _ZN15wxEventLoopBase3RunEv + 65
    21  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.0.0.dylib    0x0000000105042d97 _ZN16wxAppConsoleBase8MainLoopEv + 103
    22  _core_.so                           0x0000000104d5641c _ZN7wxPyApp8MainLoopEv + 76
    23  _core_.so                           0x0000000104da0d4f _wrap_PyApp_MainLoop + 79
    24  Python                              0x000000010479012f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16242
    25  Python                              0x000000010478c093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
    26  Python                              0x0000000104733796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809
    27  Python                              0x0000000104715f72 PyObject_Call + 101
    28  Python                              0x00000001047209a7 PyMethod_New + 1200
    29  Python                              0x0000000104715f72 PyObject_Call + 101
    30  Python                              0x000000010478fdf5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416
    31  Python                              0x0000000104792864 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 829
    32  Python                              0x000000010478f4d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
    33  Python                              0x0000000104792864 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 829
    34  Python                              0x000000010478f4d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
    35  Python                              0x000000010478c093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
    36  Python                              0x000000010478ba24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    37  Python                              0x00000001047aac2c PyParser_ASTFromFile + 306
    38  Python                              0x00000001047aacd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137
    39  Python                              0x00000001047aa821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718
    40  Python                              0x00000001047bb363 Py_Main + 2995
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff958bd5fd start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Process finished with exit code 134
```

Comment: Please provide a small runnable sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hello RobinDunn, you can see the whole code here: https://github.com/lrajmohan/PyView
The problem arises in :  https://github.com/lrajmohan/PyView/blob/master/ExpSuite%20-%20Copy/ExpSuite/PyView/PyView.py ,while pressing the lever button.

Comment: I guess I should have put more emphasis on the word "small".  See also  http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps